# Is there a convenient function or PHP function for converting associative array values into individual variables?

Tags: php

I have this repetitive code to avoid ugly variable names:

```
    $user_info       = $_SESSION['cmr']['user_info'];
    $official1_email = $_SESSION['cmr']['official1_email'];
    $official2_email = $_SESSION['cmr']['official2_email'];
    $official1_phone = $_SESSION['cmr']['official1_phone'];
    $official2_phone = $_SESSION['cmr']['official2_phone'];
    $official1_name  = $_SESSION['cmr']['official1_name'];
    $official2_name  = $_SESSION['cmr']['official2_name'];
    $office1_name    = $_SESSION['cmr']['office1_name'];
    $office2_name    = $_SESSION['cmr']['office2_name'];
    $md5             = $_SESSION['cmr']['cmr_md5'];
```

In perl, with strict and warnings turned off, I'd do something like this:

```
$hash{'cmr'} = {  'one' => 2, 'three' => 4, 'five' => 6 };
${$_} = $hash{'cmr'}{$_} for keys %{$hash{'cmr'}};
print $one;

# outputs "2"
```

Wondering if there is something similar in PHP I could do to keep the code cleaner and less full of square brackets.

Comment: [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) will create variables from the array keys and values: `extract($_SESSION['cmr'])`. However, I would call that the opposite of "clean" and usually not recommended. If you keep them in an array, they are contained. Also be careful about any existing variables with the same name. By default, they will be overwritten.

Comment: OK, thanks. Docs say extract() isn't a good idea on data that's not trusted. Hmmm. I just hate having those big long arrays directly in the code. Makes it harder for me to read and the make lines really long.

Comment: Regarding the untrusted data, it's data that comes from other sources that you don't control, like user inputs ($_GET/$_POST/$_COOKIE/API's/From files etc). Since those are user inputs, the user can add what ever key/value they want which will create (and overwrite) the variables you have in your code. That could cause both bugs/side effects and security issues. There's a reason why most people recommend against using that function. It clutters the global namespace with unnecessary (and in worse cases, unknown)

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuffing some of the user input from forms into these session variables. I do sanitize the input data first first but probably better to be safe than sorry.